# converting format of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using an `AJAX` query to `Fuseki`, that I want to visualize in a [D3.js collapsable tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). However Fuseki returns the `JSON` in a format that the `D3.js` code does not recognise. like this:

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "s" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {

        "s": {

           "type": "uri",

           "value": "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl#FourCheesesTopping"

        },

        "p": {

           "type": "uri",

           "value": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"

        },

        "o": {

           "type": "uri",

           "value": "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl#CheeseTopping"

        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to convert this JSON into this format:
         {

```
        "name": "Pizza",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl#PizzaBase",
                "children": [
                ]
            },
            {
               "name": "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl#PizzaTopping",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl#MeatTopping",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl#HotSpicedBeefTopping"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

I have tried taking the JSON and putting it into a new object with the correct format, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
            var parent = new Object();
    var childArray=[];
    var child =  [];


        function createChildObj(_children, children, depth, id, childName, parent, x, x0, y, y0){
            var childObj = new Object();
                childObj._children = _children;
                childObj.children = children;
                childObj.depth = depth;
                childObj.id =id;

                childObj.name = childName;
                childObj.parent= parent;
                childObj.x = x;
                childObj.x0 = x0;
                childObj.y = y;
                childObj.y0 = y0;   
            return childObj;

            };
            console.log(root.length)
        for (var i=0; i<root.length; i++){
            var childName = root[i]["s"]["value"];
            var childObj =  createChildObj("children",null, 1, 2, childName, parent, 190, 190, 180, 180);
            child.push(childObj);           
        }
        parent.name = "Pizza";
        parent.depth = 0;
        parent.id = 3;
        parent.children= child;
        parent.x0 = root.x0;
        parent.x = parent.x0;
        parent.y0 = root.y0;
        parent.y = parent.y0;
```

So I am aiming to have `parent` as the JSON object with the data in the correct format to parse to the `d3`. sorry its a mess, been fiddling for ages trying to learn D3, and the learning curve is steeper than I had anticipated. Any help would be great! cheers.

Comment: How would the JSON data look like if the children were to have its own children?

Comment: edited question to show children with children, thanks!

Comment: What about the original JSON data you're getting from Fuseki?

Comment: Edited question to show, I think the issue is that it shows no hierachy within the structure of data, it is data from and OWL file that establishes a parent-child hierarchy using the URI `"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"`.